# Custom message when mvn install completes?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-install-plugin

I'd like to display a string of characters on the console when mvn install completes
(ie something the user is likely to see).

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: For what reason do you need this? Isn't "build successful" not enough?

Comment: Actually, I want to say something like "Don't forget to subscribe to the developers mailing list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that pupose just try the [maven-echo-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/Maven-Echo-Plugin) bound to the correct lifecycle phase:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>echo</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <echos>
      <echo>+----------------------------------------------------------+</echo>
      <echo>!   DON'T FORGET TO SUBSCRIBE TO DEVELOPERS MAILING LIST   !</echo>
      <echo>+----------------------------------------------------------+</echo>
    </echos>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```